# Interaction between joint qubit quantum system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, tensor-calculus, interactions, bloch-sphere

Consider the following interaction Hamiltonian
$$H = \hbar \mu \sigma_{x} \otimes \sigma_x = \hbar \mu ( |01 \rangle \langle 1 0 | + |10\rangle\langle 01|)$$ acting on the joint states of qubits $\rho_{prim} \otimes \rho_{aux}$ for $t = \frac{\pi}{2 \mu}$. It is stated that if the primary and auxiliary systems (respectively $\rho_{prim}$ and $\rho_{aux}$) are in the state $|0\rangle$ then the interaction doesn't change the primary but if the primary is in state $|1\rangle$ and auxiliary in state $|0\rangle$ then the primary flips to $|0\rangle$.

**For the first case my *revised* working is as follows**: 
We have $$e^{-i\frac{\pi \sigma_x \otimes \sigma_x}{2}}[|0\rangle \langle0 |\otimes|0\rangle \langle0|]e^{i\frac{\pi \sigma_x \otimes \sigma_x}{2}}$$ where the state of the primary is $$e^{-\frac{\pi \sigma_x}{2}}|0\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -i \\
-i & 0
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\0\\ 
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
0  \\
-i 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Why on earth should a Hamiltonian act on $\rho$ the way you describe it?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch This is an example from Kurt Jacobs "Quantum Measurement Theory and Applications", see chapter 5 on quantum control theory.

Comment: Yes, but I'm sure his Hamiltonian does not act on $\rho$ by left multiplication.  This is not even hermitian!

Comment: @NorbertSchuch It is Hermitian $\sigma_x \otimes \sigma_x = \sigma_x \sigma_x^T = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: But $H\rho$ is not Hermitian. What would it represent?

Comment: With your edits, this is no longer a question, and in addition, the answer makes no sense any more whatsoever.  You should roll back to the question you actually had and, if you wish, BELOW that post an edit where you explain the resolution yourself.  (Or, if you wish, post an answer yourself.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evolving a state $\rho$ according to an Hamiltonian $H$ does not work that way: $H\rho$ is *not* the evolved state (nor, in general, even a state at all).

The evolution with the Hamiltonian $H$ for time $t$ is described by the *unitary* operator $e^{-itH}$. To evolve a density matrix you have to compute $e^{-itH}\rho e^{itH}$.

Comment: Not that this makes the original statement in the question correct.  (Well, in some sense maybe, but not the way it is phrased.)