# Does entanglement swapping happen instantaneously?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Is entanglement swapping instantaneous?
Suppose photons 1 and 2 are entangled.  And, 3 and 4 are entangled.
A Bell-state measurement (BSM) is performed on photons 2 and 3 to cause entanglement swapping so 1 and 4 are now entangled.  Was the entanglement of 1 and 4 instantaneous (right when the BSM was performed)?

I believe this question is different than others like [Does entanglement have a speed or is it instantaneous](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68412/does-entanglement-have-a-speed-or-is-it-instantaneous).
I am asking about the swapping action.

Comment: There's no need to mention entanglement here.  You can ask the more general question:  in quantum mechanics, does a measurement cause an instantaneous change of state?  The answer is yes.

Comment: Swapping is just teleportation of one half of an entangled state. So the samw story applies as for teleportation.