# Entangled particles interaction with other particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

Non-physicist question:

Suppose two particles A and B are entangled and A collides with another particle. What happens to B?

Comment: Uh...nothing? Perhaps you should look through some of the other entanglement questions on this site and try to ask a more precise question.

Comment: Nothing, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/122467/28512.

Comment: You might be interested by the [Quantum teleportation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_teleportation) protocol.