# Is the equation $E=mc^2$ universal for any 4-dimensional spacetime?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, multiverse

Assuming a multi-verse theory and an alternative universe which spacetime is however still 4-dimesnional *(i.e. three spatial and one temporal dimensions)* but with a maximum speed of causlaity that is $υ>c$ would then the energy to effective rest mass converison equation $E=mυ^2$ still hold?

Answer (score 3):

Answering what I think is the core of your question: the $c$ in $E = mc^2$ is the speed of causality, not the speed of electromagnetic waves (aka light). In some hypothetical alternate scenario where light did not travel at the maximum possible speed, the equations of relativity would use the maximum speed, not the speed of light. This is because all the logic of relativity follows from having an invariant speed that is the same for all observers. We call it the speed of light because it is and because that's how we do experiments, but being the speed at which light travels is not the point.

And as an aside, multiverse theory is not really a thing outside of science fiction. There is no field of physics that considers alternate universes with different laws of physics. But I think this wasn't the main point of your question.

Comment: Just a thought..and observation a much larger maximum speed of information transfer $υ>>c$ would imply that we could have enormous energy but with an effective tiny rest mass. Sorry, but I cannot ignore the emperical observation and make the connection that this is exactly what vacuum free space appears to be thus vacuum and dark phantom energy being possible superluminal.

Comment: Special relativity has been tested to extremely high precision, and it seems like the speed of causality is indeed the speed of light. There's really no room for a much larger speed - it would be easily and immediately observable.

Comment: "There's really no room for a much larger speed - it would be easily and immediately observable." But it is, it is called QM.

Comment: No, QM doesn't allow for faster than light communication. See for example https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/100864/the-choice-of-measurement-basis-on-one-half-of-an-entangled-state-affects-the-ot

Comment: QM is not a frozen theory but under continious development and investigation. Please read the recent articles https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/ab76f7  and https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6382/acad60

Comment: https://www.thebrighterside.news/post/faster-than-light-travel-reveals-a-surprising-different-universe  An outline synopsis of Dragan's and Ekert ralated work.