# Why should our Knowledge of an Experiment Affect it's Outcome?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observers, quantum-eraser

The "Delayed Choice Quantum Eraser" experiment shows that our knowledge of an experiment affects it's outcome. Why is this?

Comment: The DCQE has in general been debunked ... or proven false....

Answer (score 1):

[The photon is an elementary particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_particle) in the mainstream standard model of particle physics.

> [While delayed-choice experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed-choice_quantum_eraser) have confirmed the seeming ability of measurements made on photons in the present to alter events occurring in the past, *this requires a non-standard view of quantum mechanics.* If a photon in flight is interpreted as being in a so-called "superposition of states", i.e. *if it is interpreted as something that has the potentiality to manifest as a particle or wave, but during its time in flight is neither, then there is no time paradox.* The superposition of states is the standard interpretation of quantum mechanics, and recent experiments have supported it.

Italics mine to stress that the problem exists in non-mainstream- theories of quantum mechanics for particles. There is no problem with mainstream ones, and this site discusses mainstream physics questions.